# Proper way for one website to keep another alive in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

Basically I have a website that will run a background task to perform some "maintenance" duties while it's not idle. When it is idle, these processes do not need to run.

Now I have a secondary website (virtual directory under main site) that needs to execute these tasks as well. However they can't both run them at the same time or it will cause issues.

Now the more correct solution would probably be to either merge the sites, break out the tasks into a different application, or change the tasks so that they do not conflict with each other if they're both running at the same time. For one reason or another, these are not (currently) options.

So basically when the secondary website is active, what would be the best way to make sure the primary website is awake and running these tasks?

I'm thinking the easiest solution would be to include a reference to the main website from the secondary website, so that any page load on the secondary website would force the first website to be server the request. Something like a 1px image.

But would this be better solved through IIS? Should they share the same application pool? Both applications are relatively stable, so I'm not too worried about one website bringing down the other.

Comment: write a 1 method web service per site and use that from the other side to check whatever you need of the back end.

Comment: Note that this isn't the right tool for the job. You should have a Windows Service / Scheduled job to either do the maintenance or call the page on your website and get it to do the maintenance. Note that if the job is long-lived, you need to mess around with timeouts and resource limits to prevent it being killed - which can have a negative effect elsewhere on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confused.  At one point you say that the two sites can't run the task at the same time, but then you say that when the secondary is active the primary should also be active?

Assuming your goal is to have the task run only in one place at a time, you basically having a locking problem.  Some solutions would be:

- Maintain a lock (e.g. physical file, database entry, ...) and only run the task if the other site isn't holding the lock.
- Make the task callable in site A and then have site B call it rather than running the task itself.  Site A can then track if it is already running the task.
- All the solutions you listed yourself (especially separating background tasks away from websites altogether) which are better solutions than the above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't give the secondary website the ability to run the task. That's why it has to depend on the primary site to do so. That's why when the secondary site is active the primary site also has to be. So I don't think it's really a locking problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to depend on running an automated task on a web service. If the application pool is recycled then that task will become lost and the process could lose its integrity. There is no guarantee that the process will degrade nicely when the application pool is collected.

Running a dedicated task is better handled by a system which is set up to be dedicated. Namely, the server hosting this web service. I think you would be better suited to have the host service run directly on the server locally instead of exposed to the web as a web service.

However, if that is not an option, then you will probably benefit from merging them as you state. This way as long as the application pool is alive from the child service, the parent service will be available.  Similarly, you could have them share an application pool.  The issue here is as stated above, the integrity of the dedicated process could become compromised.

.NET is not really designed to run dedicated background tasks. That is better suited to a desktop application which supports the web service.